# Book about a man in a hot air balloon, passes out and wakes up on another planet

Tags: story-identification, books

I've had this book discussed in my classes some years ago, have been looking for it ever since.
In the book, the man is the first to try and reach outer space (it's placed some time in the past), he gets so high that he blacks out from the lack of oxygen or something, he later wakes up on what seems to be a different planet. He finds a brass tag in the dirt with some faded lettering on it. The whole books is really vague, and you never really know if it all really happend, because the book was written by the man who supposedly performed this stunt.

That's about all I know,
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did the tag say ZARDoZ on it?

Comment: The Gun is Good!

Comment: No the tag had decayed to the point where the text wasn't legible.

Comment: Thats the closest anyone has ever gotten, I'm starting to get excited :D

Comment: You mention a hot air balloon in the title, but there's nothing about it in the question itself. Does the man ascend in a hot air balloon?

Comment: "Some years ago"? Is "some" closer to 60 or 30?

Comment: He does indeed ascend in it, but after that my own memory fails me. The year was not specified to my recollection.

Comment: @Chenmunka - Full text here; http://www.eapoe.org/works/tales/unphlle.htm

Answer (score 1):

Edgar Allen Poe's [*The Unparalleled Adventure Of One Hans Pfaall*](http://www.eapoe.org/works/tales/unphlle.htm) has a similar plot to your description.

The hero of the story, Hans Pfaall, travels in a hot air balloon as you describe, at some point losing consciousness due to the lack of air.

He travels to the moon, not to another planet.  The story describes the journey in detail, in the form of a diary and does have the vagueness that you describe.

I don't recall any mention of a brass plate, although he does describe the view of Earth from the moon as copper in appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are talking about **Oz Series** by L. Frank Baum. A movie "Oz the Great and Powerful" is made which is inspired from it.

Comment: Unfortunately not